# Избавиться от отступов

Tags: html, jquery, css

есть ссылки при нажатии на них открывается блок и после открытия появляется отступ,если текста мало.

```
$('a.plus').click(function(){
  var noteHeight = $('.note').height();
  var next = $(this).next();

  next.toggleClass("open");
  if(next.hasClass("open")) {
    next.css({'height': noteHeight});
  } else {
    next.css({'height': 0});
  }
  return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/gs118p1d/2/

Предполагаю,что тут как то нужно вместо этого

```
var noteHeight = $('.note').height();
```

что то типо такого

```
 var noteHeight = $(this).find('.note').height();
```

Но не работает

Comment: Что за отступ? Вы хотите что бы блок был заданной величины если текста не хватает? Что если спользовать CSS (`min-height: 400px;`)?

Comment: Отступ,вот,к примеру,нажмите ссылку 2,я хочу чтобы `height auto` был

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените:

```
var noteHeight = $('.note').height();
```

на

```
var noteHeight = $(this).next().children().height();
```

Пример:

```js
$('a.plus').click(function() {
  var noteHeight = $(this).next().children().height();

  var next = $(this).next();

  next.toggleClass("open");
  if (next.hasClass("open")) {
    next.css({
      'height': noteHeight
    });
  } else {
    next.css({
      'height': 0
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
.more {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10px;
  transition: .3s;
}
.open {
  height: auto;
  transition: .3s;
}
.note {
  background: #22dd66;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="plus">ссылка</a>
<div class="more">
  <div class="note">
    <p>Федеральный закон от 02.05.2015 N 122-ФЗ</p>
    <p>"О внесении изменений в Трудовой кодекс Российской Федерации и статьи 11 и 73 Федерального закона "Об образовании в Российской Федерации"</p>
    <p>Начало действия документа - 01.07.2016</p>
    <p>Приказом Минтруда России от 19 октября 2015 г. N 728н утвержден профессиональный стандарт "Аудитор". Этот документ представляет собой характеристику квалификации, необходимой работнику для осуществления аудиторской деятельности и оказания прочих связанных
      с ней услуг.</p>
    <p>Приказом Минтруда России от 19 октября 2015 г. N 728н утвержден профессиональный стандарт "Аудитор". Этот документ представляет собой характеристику квалификации, необходимой работнику для осуществления аудиторской деятельности и оказания прочих связанных
      с ней услуг.</p>
  </div>
</div>



<a class="plus">ссылка</a>
<div class="more">
  <div class="note">
    <p>Федеральный закон от 02.05.2015 N 122-ФЗ</p>
    <p>Приказом Минтруда России от 19 октября 2015 г. N 728н утвержден профессиональный стандарт "Аудитор". Этот документ представляет собой характеристику квалификации, необходимой работнику для осуществления аудиторской деятельности и оказания прочих связанных
      с ней услуг.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="plus">ссылка</a>
<div class="more">
  <div class="note">
    <p>Федеральный закон от 02.05.2015 N 122-ФЗ</p>
    <p>Приказом Минтруда России от 19 октября 2015 г. N 728н утвержден профессиональный стандарт "Аудитор". Этот документ представляет собой характеристику квалификации, необходимой работнику для осуществления аудиторской деятельности и оказания прочих связанных
      с ней услуг.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.plus').click(function(){
  var noteHeight = $(this).find('.note').height();
  var next = $(this).next();
  next.toggleClass("open");

 if(next.hasClass("open")) {
   next.css('height', noteHeight+'px');
 } else {
   next.css({'height': 0});
}
return false;
});
```

var noteHeight = $(this).find('.note').height(); - узнаем высоту конкретного блока

next.css('height', noteHeight+'px'); - присвоение высоты

Comment: В этом случае пропадает плавность `transition` и работает 1 раз,если закрыть ,то снова не откроется

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт не имеет смысла так как есть более простой вариант решения: 
Оставляем скрипт открытия вкладок:

```
$('a.plus').click(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  next.toggleClass("open");
});
```

Меняем CSS:

```
.more {overflow:hidden;transition:1s;height:auto;max-height:10px;}
.open {max-height: 999px;transition:1s;}
.note{background:#22dd66;height: auto;}
```

Вот пример на JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/gs118p1d/15/

Правка: добавил min-height: 0 для transition анимации.

Comment: `transition` не работает

Comment: @zkolya исправил

Comment: Отступ все равно есть, и фиксировано не вариант `min-height:200px;` текста может быть больше.Вот пока не знаю что делать

Comment: @zkolya Я указал min-height это значит минимальная высота. Если текста будет больше то все будет так же работать. Проверьте сами, я скинул рабочий пример. Кстати СТОП. Вы хотели убрать отступ, а я его добавил специально думая что вам он нужен. Сейчас исправлю :)

Comment: Стойте,я что то запутался,вот так супер работает  `.open {height:auto;transition:.3s;}` но тогда не плавно все

Comment: @zkolya если быть кратким то в плавности вся проблема. height: auto не позволит плавности работать, нужно указывать величину, статическую, например 200px, но тогда будут отступы, иначе не будет плавности. Но есть один вариант, но имеет некий лаг в конце, обновляю ответ.

Comment: Вот товарищ выше не поленился и исправил скрипт. Мой вариант более простой - я за верстку "без скриптов" :)

Comment: Спасибо!!!Что помогли)